# D3 Mouseover for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, mouseover, eventhandler

I am trying to highlight some of my svg elements when mouseover at a specific element.

So, i got elements like one big circle, small circles for every node, a line for every node, a text for every node.

What I can do is something like this:

```
on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
      .style("fill", '#0da4d3');})
```

But I want to use the mouseover method for more than the element in which I am adding the code.

For example, when selecting the big root circle, I want to use mouseover for rootcircle, all texts, the lines and all small circles.

Comment: Are the other items children of the element, that triggers the mouseover event? In that case you can go with simple selects `d3.select(this).select('.myredcircle'); ` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use d3 [selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections). For example, to select all circles:

```
on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill", '#0da4d3');})
```

Comment: Hey 3906922, Thanks for your help! it worked. - But when I want to highlight the node-specific text, line and circle when selecting one of the three parts.. They aren't in one Svg group. How do I have to proceed? Put them in one svg group? Thanks